# Combine multiple /^(xyz)/ regex expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, grep

I'm a little stuck trying to figure out the correct regular expression syntax for the following:

consider this input :

`var input = "sdkfjhd board hjh alabama jdjd bat";`

to be matched against

`var arr = ["Board of Pre University Education", "Alabama Autonomous Board", "Batman Gotham Bruce", "Superman KalEl Clark", "Board of Whatever"];`

```
var split_input = input.split(' ').join(")|^(");
var re = new RegExp("^(" + split_input + ")", "i"); // /^(sdkfjhd)|^(board)|^(hjh)|^(alabama)|^(jdjd)|^(bat)/i
```

I thought combining multiple ^(xyz) expressions with | operator will work as the OR operator short-circuits if the left condition is true and first match anything that starts with 'sdkfjhd', if found then only match items that start with 'sdkfjhd'.. otherwise, proceed to the next string 'board' and so on..
so following code

```
var result = $.grep(arr, function( a ){
    return re.test(a);
});
```

produces this output:

```
["Board of Pre University Education", "Alabama Autonomous Board", "Batman Gotham Bruce", "Board of Whatever"]
```

where I just want it to be

```
["Board of Pre University Education", "Board of Whatever"]
```

So if any left side expression finds a match first, I'm trying to find out a way to skip all the right side expressions. Considering the same input string `"sdkfjhd board hjh alabama jdjd bat"`... 'sdkfjhd' will not produce any result so it moves on to 'board', board finds a match and produces 2 results : `["Board of Pre University Education", "Board of Whatever"]`. Now as its found 1 or more matches, it shouldn't move to the next expressions i.e. 'hjh','alabama','jdjd' or 'batman'. Hope its more clear, thanks!

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks :)!

PS: Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4h26vLq8/40/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex works as it should. The | works as OR but you don't match word boundaries. Therefore:

1. Board of Pre University Education // matches by board
2. Alabama Autonomous Board // matches by alabama and board
3. Batman Gotham Bruce // matches by bat
4. Superman KalEl Clark // doesn't match
5. Board of Whatever // matches by board

The 'i' as second parameter in the `new RegExp` indicates a case-insentive regexp.

You can use word boundaries \b to match only whole words:

```
var split_input = input.split(' ').join("\\b)|^(\\b");
var re = new RegExp("^(\\b" + split_input + "\\b)", "i");
```

For word general match not just the first word you can remove the ^ from the regexp:

```
var split_input = input.split(' ').join("\\b)|(\\b");
var re = new RegExp("(\\b" + split_input + "\\b)", "i");
```

**Edit:** After some comments for clearification:
It should only get the matches from the first word hit in the input string:

```
var input = "sdkfjhd batman hjh jdjd alabama board";
var arr = ["Board of Pre University Education", "Alabama Autonomous Board", "Batman Gotham Bruce", "Superman KalEl Clark", "Board of Whatever"];

var split_input = input.split(/\s+/);
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i <split_input.length; i++){
    var exp = new RegExp('^\\b'+split_input[i]+'\\b', 'ig');
    for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++){
        if (exp.test(arr[n])){
            result.push(arr[n]);
        }
    }
    if (result.length > 0)
        break;
}
```

As 'batman' in the string matches one or more items in array, it should no longer proceed further with next expressions i.e 'hjh' 'jdjd' 'alabama' 'board'.
hence produce the following result:

```
["Batman Gotham Bruce"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "Alabama Autonomous Board // matches by broad and alabama" < This only works because of 'Alabama' in the exp, If I remove Alabama from input string, it wouldn't match with Board because it doesn't start with it.

Comment: The ^ character indicates the start of a sentance. If you remove the ^ it should test each word in the string. I updated the answer.

Comment: Right, If I use your system http://jsfiddle.net/4h26vLq8/52/ with "sdkfjhd board hjh jdjd bat" string, It only produces results with items that start with Board, But it I change bat to batman in the input string, then it finds batman too, hence 3 results. What I'm trying to achieve here is, If board finds results, it should stop right there and shouldn't move forward. If I have input string as "batman sdkfjhd board hjh jdjd" then it should only show items that start with batman and skip the rest.

Comment: Well, if you complete bat to batman, it will show up in the results, because its matching word against word using \b. not sure if there's a way to skip the rest if any left side expression finds a match first. Thanks

Comment: Simon, this now only produces 1 result, but there are 2 items in the array that start with "Board". Perhaps I'm not being so good at explaining what I'm trying to achieve. Sorry about that. 

I'll try again: Considering the same input string "sdkfjhd board hjh jdjd batman"... 'sdkfjhd' will not produce any result so it moves on to 'board', board finds a match and produces 2 results : ["Board of Pre University Education", "Board of Whatever"]. Now as its found 1 or more matches, it shouldn't move to the next expression in the string i.e. 'hjh' or 'jdjd' or 'batman'. Hope its more clear, thanks!

Comment: Check your spelling Simon.  "broad" is never going to match "Board"

Comment: Maybe I should stop posting for today. Thanks again.

Comment: Still one more... I give up.

Comment: Yes! Simon, Just a little correction, I added ^ in front of the expression, only to match those items that start with the given expression. But This works great! http://jsfiddle.net/hjcvtqzh/10/ 

I'll mark yours as answer, I guess If you wanna edit it with this solution?

Comment: I updated the answer, thanks. And I hope I've found all broads. :(

Comment: lol! Thanks a lot Simon, I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. I've marked your solution as answer. Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include start anchor `^` for every word, you can use:

```
var arr = ["Board of Pre University Education", "Alabama Autonomous Board", "Batman Gotham Bruce", "Superman KalEl Clark", "Board of Whatever"];

var input = "sdkfjhd board hjh alabama jdjd bat";

var split_input = input.split(' ').join("|");
var re = new RegExp("^(" + split_input + ")\\b", "i");

console.log(re);
//=> /^(sdkfjhd|board|hjh|alabama|jdjd|bat)\b/i

var result = $.grep(arr, function( a ){
    return re.test(a);
});

console.log( result );
//=> ["Board of Pre University Education", "Alabama Autonomous Board", "Board of Whatever"]
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7m4ft93s/)

Comment: thanks for replaying. I do not want "Alabama Autonomous Board" to show in results as its already found matching items with "Board".. not sure if there's a way to skip the rest if any left side expression finds a match first. Thanks

Comment: That actually complicates the problem, can you edit the question add this as requirement and I will try to find a working solution.

Comment: Following that logic even `"Board of Whatever"` won't be found right?

Comment: No, that should be there as it starts with 'Board'. Like considering this as input string "sdkfjhd batman hjh jdjd board", it should only show 1 result i.e. item that starts with Batman and skip any right side expressions that may produce more results.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by **if any left side expression finds a match first, I'm trying to find out a way to skip the rest**